# Amazon athena with big gzip json files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Im taking my first steps with amazon athena and i dont know why im not getting the expected results.

Im dealing with big json files, encoded in gzip and stored in s3, and i cannot get results for even a simple count query.

Now im testing with two files, each one with about 10gb of compressed json.
When i test the table, with the limit 10, i get the results, so the table is created and working, but when i have to make another query, even with a simple where, the query never ends, i mean, i had to stop it when reaching 30 minutes without response.

Ive read about data partitioning and i know big files its not the best option to store data in s3 if you want to use athena.

Despite of this, ive been searching a little in internet and get to some test where people query over big files (70-80gb) obtaining the result in about 10 second.

The use of athena seems very easy, but there must be something im doing wrong in addittion to the unpartitioned data.

Could you give any tips, or there is no solution for this situation.

Thank you

Comment: I wonder whether there is a problem with the data in the file(s)? A `LIMIT` command stops once the limit is reached, so it might not be hitting the problem spot. Also, JSON data is not well-optimized for queries. If you are wanting to query lots of data in Amazon Athena, it would be worth converting it to Parquet format.

Comment: As suggested by @JohnRotenstein use Parquet format. We also had similar use case of xml files which we solved using parquet as intermediate format for fetching data through athena.

Comment: So is this situation the normal behaviour of athena with big json files?
I was wondering if there is a problem with the compression or something.
Results are really bad, i cannot even filter anything with a query with only a where field.